# ShinyMCE does not work in renderUI and shinyDashboard

Tags: r, shiny, tinymce

This MWE is working:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyMCE)

ui<-dashboardPage(header=dashboardHeader(),
                  sidebar=dashboardSidebar(),
                  body=dashboardBody(#uiOutput("body")
                                     tinyMCE("tinyInput","Some html text")
                                     ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #output$body <- renderUI({tinyMCE('tinyInput',"Some html text")})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

However, if I use the `tinyMCE` inside `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyMCE)

ui<-dashboardPage(header=dashboardHeader(),
                  sidebar=dashboardSidebar(),
                  body=dashboardBody(uiOutput("body")
                                     #tinyMCE("tinyInput","Some html text")
                                     ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$body <- renderUI({tinyMCE('tinyInput',"Some html text")})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

..it does not work properly:

[image]

I need to use `renderUI` because I have several elements to render in the body.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in [here](https://github.com/mul118/shinyMCE/issues/1).
I added the source of the script in a singleton:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyMCE)

ui<-dashboardPage(header=dashboardHeader(),
                  sidebar=dashboardSidebar(),
                  body=dashboardBody(singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "//cdn.tiny.cloud/1/5a5deew2z9gml5pwn95iosioop446qny3vyfh994kujzkwu6/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js", referrerpolicy="origin"))),
                                     uiOutput("body")
                                     #tinyMCE("tinyInput","Some html text")
                                     ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$body <- renderUI({tinyMCE('tinyInput',"Some html text")})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It fixed my problem.